# Real Analysis, Continuous functions.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f : [0, 1]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function.

If there exists $c\in(0, 1)$ such that $f(c)\leq f(x)$ for every
$x\in[0, 1]$, show that there exist $a,b\in[0, 1]$  such that $a\neq b$ and $f(a) = f(b)$.

Comment: What do you propose as an approach to this problem? Also, which theorems do you know(Intermediate  value theorem / Bolzano's theorem)? This will help us in answering the question.

Comment: The theorem i believe is the intermediate value theorem,

Answer (score 1):

If $f(0)=f(1)$ we can take $a=0,b=1$. Otherwise we may assume that $f(0)<f(1)$ since a similar argument argument works when $f(0)>f(1)$. Let $t \in (f(c),f(0)])$. [Note that if $f(0)=f(c)$ the  there is nothing to prove].  Now apply intermediate value property to the intervals $[0,c]$ and $[c,1]$ to get points $a$ in the first interval and $b$ in the second such that $f(a)=f(b)=t$. [$t$ also lies between $f(c)$ and $f(1)$].  It is easy to see that $a=b$ is not possible because $t >f(c)$

Comment: the thm states f(a) does not equal f(b) so i could try prove this by contradiction

Comment: @Adayah Thanks for pointing out the silly mistake.  I have corrected the proof.

Comment: @ryanfoot You are supposed to find $a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ but $a \neq b$.

Comment: Why $t$ lies between other interval. What is the geometric idea of this problem? Can you give me some insight?

Comment: We already have $f(c)<t$. We also have $t \leq f(0)<f(1)$ so $t<f(1)$. If you draw the graph of $f$ you can see that there are lots of points $a,b$ with $f(a)=f(b)$ and $a \neq b$. Just draw horizontal lines above the line $y=f(c)$ but not too far above this line. You will see that the graph meets the line at two point. My $t$ stands for the $y-$ coordinates of these lines.

Comment: Sorry to ping you again can you give a concrete example where $f(c)$ is not equal to $f(0)$ and $f(0)$ is not equal to $ f(1)$. I tried but i am not able to come up with a continuous function with such properties. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $a=-1,b=1,f(x)=x^{2}$. Here $c=0$. Don't hesitate to ask questions!

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use following fact?

- An injective continuous real function $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on an interval $I$ is strictly monotone.

If yes you can reason as follows by contradiction:

- Assume $f$ is injective.
- $f(c) = \min_{x \in [0,1]} f(x) \stackrel{f \mbox{ strictly monotone}}{\Longrightarrow} c= 0$ or $c= 1$
- That's a contradiction to the assumed $c \in (0,1)$.
- It follows that $f$ cannot be injective, hence $\exists a,b \in [0,1]: a \neq b, f(a)=f(b)$

Comment: This is simple and straightforward. Wow!!

Answer (score 0):

If there exists a,b such that f(a)=f(b)=f(c),then we are done. Therefore, we consider another case. Take a small neighborhood of c,$U=[c-\epsilon,c],V=[c,c+\epsilon]$,f has a maximum in $U$ ,denoted $f(d),d \in U $and f has a maximum in $V$,denoted $f(e),e\in V $since f is continued. We take $s=\min\{f(d),f(e)\}$,then we can use **intermediate value theorem** ,viz.,there exists $a\in U,b\in V$,such that $f(a)=f(b)=s$.